# Using a Numeric Stepper from one Flash file to affect gamespeed in an external Flash file? Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Currently I have an intro screen to my flash file which has two objects.
A button which will load an external flash file using:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                    
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("flashgame.swf");
```

The second thing is a Numeric Stepper, which will be from 1 to 10. If the user selects a number e.g. 3 then the game speed I have set in the flashgame.swf should be changed 
Such as:

```
var gameSpeed:uint = 10 * numericStepper.value;
```

But I think my problem is coming into place because the stepper and gamespeed are from different files.

Anyone got any idea please?

I have also tried creating a stepper in the game file and used this code:

```
var gameLevel:NumericStepper = new NumericStepper(); 
gameLevel.maximum = 10; 
gameLevel.minimum = 1; 
addChild(gameLevel); 
var gameSpeed:uint = 10 * gameLevel.value;
```

For some reason the stepper just flashes on the stage, no errors come up and the game doesn't work

Comment: Can you handle the game speed in the loaded file? Is the only problem that the value is set in its parent loader?

Comment: I have created a stepper in the game file and used this code: 
var gameLevel:NumericStepper = new NumericStepper();
gameLevel.maximum = 10;
gameLevel.minimum = 1;
addChild(gameLevel);

var gameSpeed:uint = 10 * gameLevel.value;
For some reason the stepper just flashes on the stage, no errors come up and the game doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute you code, the stepper has no chance to wait for user input.

There is no time between theese two instructions.

```
addChild(gameLevel); 
var gameSpeed:uint = 10 * gameLevel.value;
```

You should wait for user input in your NumericStepper, and then, on user event, set the game speed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Yeah I know it's kinda sad to type out all this code (especially since some people wouldn't even be grateful enough to say thanks) but I think this question is important enough to justify the code as it may be helpful to others in future also.

---

Hi,

You were close. In your game file you could have put a `var _setgameSpeed` and then from Intro you could adjust it by `flashgame._setgameSpeed =  gameSpeed;` It's a bit more complicated though since you also have to setup a reference to flashgame in the first place. Let me explain...

Ideally you want to put all your code in one place (an .as file would be best but...) if you would rather use timeline then you should create a new empty layer called "actions" and put all your code in the first frame of that.

Also change your button to a movieClip type and remove any code within it since everything will be controlled by the code in "actions" layer. In the example I have that movieclip on the stage with instance name of "btn_load_SWF"

> **Intro.swf (Parent SWF file)**

```
var my_Game_Swf:MovieClip; //reference name when accessing "flashgame.swf"
var _SWF_is_loaded:Boolean = false; //initial value
var set_gameSpeed:int; //temp value holder for speed

var swf_loader:Loader = new Loader();
btn_load_SWF.buttonMode = true; //instance name of movieclip used as "load" button
btn_load_SWF.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load_Game_SWF);

function load_Game_SWF (event:MouseEvent) : void 
{ 
 //set_gameSpeed = 10 * numericStepper.value;
 set_gameSpeed = 100; //manual set cos I dont have the above numericStepper

 if ( _SWF_is_loaded == true)
 { 
   stage.removeChild(swf_loader);
   swf_loader.load ( new URLRequest ("flashgame.swf") );
 }
 else
 {  swf_loader.load ( new URLRequest ("flashgame.swf") ); }

 swf_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Game_SWF_ready);

} 

function Game_SWF_ready (evt:Event) : void
{

  swf_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Game_SWF_ready); 

  //Treat the Loader contents (flashgame.swf) as a MovieClip named "my_Game_Swf"
  my_Game_Swf = swf_loader.content as MovieClip; 
  my_Game_Swf.gameSpeed = set_gameSpeed; //update gameSpeed variable in flashgame.swf
  //also adjust SWF placement (.x and .y positions etc) here if necessary   

  stage.addChild(my_Game_Swf);
  _SWF_is_loaded = true;

}
```

Now in you flashgame file make sure the there's also an actions layers and put in code like this below then compile it first before debugging the Intro/Parent file. When your Intro loads the flashgame.swf it should load an swf that already has the code below compiled.

> **flashgame.swf**

```
var gameSpeed:int;
gameSpeed = 0; //initial value & will be changed by parent

addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded_toStage);

function onAdded_toStage (e:Event):void
{

trace("trace gameSpeed is.." + String(gameSpeed)); //confirm speed in Debugger

//*** Example usage ***          
var my_shape:Shape = new Shape();
my_shape.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF0000, 5);
my_shape.graphics.moveTo(10, 50); 
my_shape.graphics.lineTo(gameSpeed * 10, 50); //this line length is affected by gameSpeed as set in parent SWF
addChild(my_shape);
}
```

The key line in intro.swf is this: `my_Game_Swf.gameSpeed = set_gameSpeed;` as it updates a variable in flashgame.swf (referred as my_Game_Swf) with an amount that is taken from a variable in the Parent SWF.

This is just one way you can access information between two separate SWF files. Hope it helps out.